# Move current executable c#

Tags: c#

I would like to move the currently executing assembly to the C drive. When I try the following code:

```
File.Move(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, @"c\");
```

it gives me an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Can this be fixed?

Comment: You can't move current executable because the system is opening it.

Comment: You can't move the EXE of the running program but you can copy it.

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: @duDE An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @Gewoo: Great to know it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must provide a *name* for the destination file:

```
File.Move(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, @"c:\xxx\foo.exe");
```

(Write on the root of C: requires elevation)

Comment: [Tested] I can't believe that actually worked; its copied and deleted the original file. :O

Comment: Well nothing is deleted - you can't delete a running executable, but moving is renaming which is just an update to the file system, this need not interfere with the running image.

Comment: @AlexK. , I have a question - **Can this work to _update an application_? Say, I move the file into a .bak, create a new .exe, then do** `Application.Restart();` **? Or am I missing something :D**